# Office UI Fabric React people picker not populating suggested drop down

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, office-ui-fabric

When I'm using the office ui fabric react component for people picker, it's not populating the suggested people in the dropdown.

Two errors that I'm getting are

Exception in CommandButton.render(): TypeError: Cannot read property 'palette' of undefined

and

Exception in Layer.componentDidUpdate(): Exception in CommandButton.render(): TypeError: Cannot read property 'palette' of undefined

I've only been able to find this issue on github https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/1952, but there isn't much to go on. I am using office-ui-fabric-react version 4.5.1

The query is working from what I can see because I can console.log the results and it has people in there.

Here's what it looks like right now.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { css,} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

import { IReactRequestProps } from './IReactRequestProps';

import {
  CompactPeoplePicker,
  IBasePickerSuggestionsProps,
  ListPeoplePicker,
  NormalPeoplePicker
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Pickers';

import { IPersonaProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Persona';
const suggestionProps: IBasePickerSuggestionsProps = {
  suggestionsHeaderText: 'Suggested People',
  noResultsFoundText: 'No results found',
  loadingText: 'Loading'
};

import {
  BaseComponent,
  assign,
  autobind
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib//Utilities';

import { people } from './PeoplePickerExampleData';
import { Label } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label';
import { IPeopleDataResult } from './IPeopleDataResult';
import { IPersonaWithMenu } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/pickers/PeoplePicker/PeoplePickerItems/PeoplePickerItem.Props';
import { IContextualMenuItem } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ContextualMenu';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export interface IOfficeUiFabricPeoplePickerState {
  currentPicker?: number | string;
  delayResults?: boolean;
}
export interface IPeopleSearchProps {
  JobTitle: string;
  PictureURL: string;
  PreferredName: string;
}


export default class ReactRequest extends React.Component<IReactRequestProps, IOfficeUiFabricPeoplePickerState> {
  private _peopleList;
  private contextualMenuItems: IContextualMenuItem[] = [
    {
      key: 'newItem',
      icon: 'circlePlus',
      name: 'New'
    },
    {
      key: 'upload',
      icon: 'upload',
      name: 'Upload'
    },
    {
      key: 'divider_1',
      name: '-',
    },
    {
      key: 'rename',
      name: 'Rename'
    },
    {
      key: 'properties',
      name: 'Properties'
    },
    {
      key: 'disabled',
      name: 'Disabled item',
      disabled: true
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._peopleList = [];
    people.forEach((persona: IPersonaProps) => {
      let target: IPersonaWithMenu = {};

      assign(target, persona, { menuItems: this.contextualMenuItems });
      this._peopleList.push(target);
    });

    this.state = {
      currentPicker: 1,
      delayResults: false
    };
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactRequestProps> {
    if (this.props.typePicker == "Normal") {
      return (
        <NormalPeoplePicker
          onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged}
          getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
          pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
          className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
          key={'normal'}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <CompactPeoplePicker
          onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChanged}
          getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
          pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
          className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
          key={'normal'}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  @autobind
  private _onFilterChanged(filterText: string, currentPersonas: IPersonaProps[], limitResults?: number) {
    if (filterText) {
      if (filterText.length > 2) {
        return this.searchPeople(filterText, this._peopleList);        
      }
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  private searchPeople(terms: string, results: IPersonaProps[]): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
    //return new Promise<IPersonaProps[]>((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(results), 2000));
    return new Promise<IPersonaProps[]>((resolve, reject) =>
      this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/search/query?querytext='*${terms}*'&rowlimit=10&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'odata-version': ''
          }
        })
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ PrimaryQueryResult: IPeopleDataResult }> => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((response: { PrimaryQueryResult: IPeopleDataResult }): void => {
          let relevantResults: any = response.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults;
          let resultCount: number = relevantResults.TotalRows;
          let people = [];
          let persona: IPersonaProps = {};
          console.log(relevantResults);
          console.log('really relevant');
          if (resultCount > 0) {
            relevantResults.Table.Rows.forEach(function (row) {
              row.Cells.forEach(function (cell) {
                //person[cell.Key] = cell.Value;
                if (cell.Key === 'JobTitle')
                  persona.secondaryText = cell.Value;
                if (cell.Key === 'PictureURL')
                  persona.imageUrl = cell.Value;
                if (cell.Key === 'PreferredName')
                  persona.primaryText = cell.Value;
              });
              people.push(persona);
            });
          }
          resolve(people);
          console.log(people);
          console.log("PEOPLE");
        }, (error: any): void => {
          reject(this._peopleList = []);
        }));
  }

  private _filterPersonasByText(filterText: string): IPersonaProps[] {
    return this._peopleList.filter(item => this._doesTextStartWith(item.primaryText, filterText));
  }

  private _removeDuplicates(personas: IPersonaProps[], possibleDupes: IPersonaProps[]) {
    return personas.filter(persona => !this._listContainsPersona(persona, possibleDupes));
  }
  private _listContainsPersona(persona: IPersonaProps, personas: IPersonaProps[]) {
    if (!personas || !personas.length || personas.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return personas.filter(item => item.primaryText === persona.primaryText).length > 0;
  }
  private _filterPromise(personasToReturn: IPersonaProps[]): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
    if (this.state.delayResults) {
      return this._convertResultsToPromise(personasToReturn);
    } else {
      return personasToReturn;
    }
  }
  private _convertResultsToPromise(results: IPersonaProps[]): Promise<IPersonaProps[]> {
    return new Promise<IPersonaProps[]>((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(results), 2000));
  }
  private _doesTextStartWith(text: string, filterText: string): boolean {
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got that error when using later versions of fabric. works fine with older versions,